# ClassLoader for children classes

Tags: java, android, service, rpc

This is my scenario:

- I have a "remote" service (local to the Android device but running on another separate process).
- I built an API to interact with this service. It's based on `Message`.
- In this API, it is required to pass some object defined by the API, e.g. instances of a custom `Entity` class.

The problem I'm having here is that for `Entity` subclasses, the service cannot unmarshall them, because obviously he doesn't know such classes (throws `ClassNotFoundException`). But all I want is to access `Entity` class functionality through this subclasses.

Is there any way to acheive this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are sending serialized java objects to your remote api, the api must know the object to deserialize it (therefore it must know each subtype of Entity). But you can try sending only Entity objects (I don't like this approach). But maybe you can try sending your objects as JSON and parse the JSON data to an Entity-Object. I'm not sure if JSON can help you, but you can give it a try. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Comment: Why not place the `Entity` subclasses on the "remote" service's classpath? Or place both the "remote" service's classpath and the current process's classpath to be the same? It seems obvious but perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: I cannot place the `Entity` subclasses anywhere because I simply don't have them. Again: this is an API. What should I do, request all subclasses source to third-party developers? :S

Comment: @zip: yes, JSON and parsing to `Entity` is a good idea. If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: As @awashburn mentioned, can't you place the .class files in the classpath of the "remote" service? You don't need the source code, just the .class files.

Comment: How would you send the `.class` to the other process? Also keep in mind that this `.class` subclass might have other dependencies I don't know about.

Comment: @m0skit0 I understand now, you did not define the subclasses that are being passed to the API; the client did through polymorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending serialized java objects to your remote API, the API must know the object to deserialize it (therefore it must know each subtype of Entity).

Maybe you can try sending your objects as JSON and parse the JSON data to an Entity-Object. I'm not sure if JSON can help you, but you can give it a try. (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Answer (score -1):

I understood well firstly u need to map the objects into the receiver try use [this](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.gr/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html)

Comment: Sorry, but looks like you did not understand. This is no Web Service. This is local service but "remote" in a sense that it's another process. It's explained on the question: *I have a "remote" service (**local to the Android device but running on another separate process**)*

Comment: ooh ok then i' mistaken :/ btw I was missing an if in above answer

Comment: Then edit it to add the *if* ;) Also [I would not use SOAP even if it was a Web Service](http://www.somebits.com/weblog/tech/bad/whySoapSucks.html).

Comment: yes it was back to when I thought it was a web service.sorry for any incovinience